# What is IQ BOT in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: automation, ocr, image-recognition, automationanywhere

What is IQ BOT in Automation Anywhere? I'm really confuse since the previous version of Automation Anywhere had already the capability of OCR and Image Recognition, what's the difference of it?

Answer (score 2):

The differences are as follows:

- Image recognition in AA refers to finding an element (e.g a button) by an image
- OCR is a function to extract text from an image
- IQBot refers to a machine trained functionality that extracts structured or semi structured data from documents, such as purchase orders or invoices. It is using OCR as a base tech for extracting text, but machine learning is involved in the actual data extraction

Comment: In addition to that, IQ bots are pre-trainied os if "Invoice Number" becomes "Invoice #" or "Invoice No.", It won't be a problem for IQ Bot

Answer (score 0):

If your question is what the difference between the IQBot in Version10 vs Version11, there isn´t. They just improved other tools, mainly the control room.

Answer (score 0):

A BOT THAT LEARNS FROM HUMAN BEHAVIOR.

IQ Bot is the only cognitive bot with vision skills that adds structure to unstructured content and learns by observing people at work increasing your digital footprint.

IQ bots use cognitive capabilities to extract information from semi and unstructured data. It also learns to detect patterns so that the next time the pattern is encountered the bot knows exactly what to do.

IQ Bot uses the OCR technology to extract information from a document.

> OCR tools measure results based on accuracy, IQ Bot uses the Straight
>   Through Processing (STP) technique to measure how many documents can
>   be processed end-to-end without human intervention

**Automates Classification**
Regulates the recognition and classification of content with leading edge unsupervised learning algorithms.

**Intelligently Digitizes**
Leverages the latest computer vision technology to more intelligently and accurately digitize documents than traditional OCR technology.

**Learns on the Job**
Continuously learns from user feedback getting ‘smarter’ over time.

**Automates End-to-end Process**
Automation Anywhere uniquely mixes and matches traditional RPA with cognitive technology to achieve unprecedented levels of STP.

***Reference:***

[IQ Bot](https://www.automationanywhere.com/images/products/IQBotBrochure.pdf)

[FAQ for IQ Bot](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/iq-bot-v6.5/page/iq-bot/topics/iq-bot/faqs-iq-bot-trials.html)